# TL072 based circuit generates loud noise

Tags: analog, audio, guitar-pedal

This circuit, designed as a bass scream, keeps generating a low noise about the same loudness as the guitar signal on the output.

[image: Scream pedal shema]

Comment: removed the self-deprecation and verbal fluff. Can you tell us what you've tried to debug this yourself already, so that we don't propose stuff you've already tried?

Comment: Have you assembled this on a bread board, as a PCB or something else? Show us a picture! :)

Comment: If the opamp is oscillating, you need to decouple its power pins with a bypass capacitor.

Comment: Oooaoh, Dave, missed the missing decoupling caps! Also, Martin, really, debug this stage by stage: you can measure S1. Only if that is OK, you'd connect the second stage.  Only if S2 is OK, the third and so on. Where exactly does it go wrong?

Comment: @DaveTweed Do you mean putting a cap between pins 8 and 4? Or a series cap on each leg?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried that. The problem was somewhere in the second stage.

Comment: Yes, between pins 8 and 4. Your first stage and second stage are both non-inverting, so if there's any inadvertent coupling between the two opamps via the power pins, the circuit could easily oscillate. This is one reason that inverting configurations tend to be preferred.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I see plenty of *coupling* capacitors, but no **de**coupling capacitors on the power supply.

Comment: What a poorly designed circuit - where did you find this trash?

Comment: The 4.5 V bias is also fed back to guitar coils. Do consider a capacitor there to block DC.

Comment: Is it running off a wall wart?  Could be AC ripple.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Bingo, mate. Ran it from  9v battery and it's OK. So I just need to isolate the PSU.

Comment: @MartinKellerII. you need to stabilize the voltage you use to generate your 4.5V, AND you need to add decoupling caps to your operational amplifiers. And you need to suppress your feedback loop, lest you're eager to find out by accident what the resonant frequency is.

Comment: @MartinKellerII. Changed to an answer for resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You have a feedback through the wet-dry circuit. That's an oscillator. The dry signal should have a buffer amp before it's fed to the wet-dry balance pot. It very likely would stop the signal going from output back to the input.

Others have already said there's no decoupling capacitors in the DC supply inputs of the opamps. That is a common unwanted feedback mechanism (=through the power rails) and can cause oscillation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to break that feedback path through the wet/dry mixer. I found this recently when reverse-engineering a powered speaker for a friend. Since the wiper of the pot is connected to ground, and the input to the opamp is held at "virtual ground", there is no signal path between the two inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUkaBQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>